# Using a variable content to generate a variable name

Tags: variables, lua

I have a script for a game server, and I'm stuck in some shit that look easy to solve

Exists a variable which receive content dynamically based on user action, so we will name this variable: example, and attrib some random value

```
local example = Potato
```

Then I have a function which sends a message to a discord webhook

```
SendWebhookMessage(varNAME, "Message content")
```

Where `varname` is the variable containing the link of the webhook.

I want to use the content of  variable example to generate the variable name like

```
webhook_ds_example
```

So in this case it will be

```
webhook_ds_potato
```

Hope you guys could understand and help to solve

````
local menu = { name = "Baú" }
local cb_take = function(idname)
local citem = chest.items[idname]
local amount = vRP.prompt(source,"Quantidade:","")

amount = parseInt(amount)

if amount >= 0 and amount <= citem.amount then
    local new_weight = vRP.getInventoryWeight(user_id)+vRP.getItemWeight(idname)*amount

if new_weight <= vRP.getInventoryMaxWeight(user_id) then                            
    citem.amount = citem.amount - amount

local temp = os.date("%x  %X")
vRP.logs("savedata/bau.txt","Bau: "..name.."        [ID]: "..user_id.." /"..temp.." [FUNÇÃO]: Retirar / [ITEM]: "..idname.." / [QTD]: "..amount)
local webhook_bau_fac1 = ""
local webhook_bau_fac2 = ""
local webhook_bau_fac3 = ""
local webhook_bau_fac4 = ""

SendWebhookMessage(webhook_bau_..name,"```prolog\n[ID]: "..user_id.." "..identity.name.." "..identity.firstname.." \n[GUARDOU]: "..vRP.format(parseInt(amount)).." "..vRP.itemNameList(itemName).." \n[BAU]: "..chestName.." "..os.date("\n[Data]: %d/%m/%Y [Hora]: %H:%M:%S").." \r```")
````

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for *tables*, which let you store lots of different named values in *one* variable.

```
local webhook_bau -- make a variable

-- create a table with 4 entries, put it in the variable 
webhook_bau = {fac1="", fac2="", fac3="", fac4=""}

-- if you want to start with an empty table, use {} instead

-- change one of them based on the name
webhook_bau[name] = "something"

-- use one of the entries based on the name
SendWebhookMessage(webhook_bau[name], "whatever you want to send")
```

Table entries "magically" appear when you use them, you don't have to create them first. If you access an entry that doesn't exist, you will read the value `nil`. You can also delete an entry by putting `nil` in the entry.

Answer (score 0):

In the example you provided, you have:

````
SendWebhookMessage(webhook_bau_..name,"```prolog\n[ID]: "..user_id.." "..identity.name.." "..identity.firstname.." \n[GUARDOU]: "..vRP.format(parseInt(amount)).." "..vRP.itemNameList(itemName).." \n[BAU]: "..chestName.." "..os.date("\n[Data]: %d/%m/%Y [Hora]: %H:%M:%S").." \r```")
````

You are missing quotes around `webhook_bau_` which would result in an error trying to concatenate a nil variable.

I'm also not seeing where `name` is set (only `menu.name`), so I'm assuming you have that elsewhere in your program, if not, that will also be nil, so just make sure that is set somewhere as well.